# Testing Angular Service in Karma: Same Test, Different Results

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test an Angular service with Karma, and was getting some strange results, so just for kicks I made two tests that were identical to see if I would get the same results, but I didn't:

```
describe('Profile Data Service', function() {
  var LoginData, rootScope, $httpBackend;
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  describe('get profile data', function() {
    beforeEach(inject(function(_LoginData_, $rootScope, _$httpBackend_) {
      LoginData = _LoginData_;
      LoginData.username= "jsmith";
      LoginData.token = "token";

      rootScope = $rootScope;

      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

    }));

    it('should get profile data on instantiation', inject(function(ProfileDataService) {
      $httpBackend.expect('POST', 'http://mytestserver.com/api/', {
        params: [{
          username: "jsmith",
          token: "token",
          method: "getProfile"
        }]
      })
      .respond({
        result: {
          address: "111 Main St."
          city: "Los Angeles",
          state: "CA"
        }
      });
      $httpBackend.flush();
      expect(ProfileDataService.profileData.address).toMatch("111 Main St.");
    }));

    it('should get profile data on instantiation', inject(function(ProfileDataService) {
      $httpBackend.expect('POST', 'http://mytestserver.com/api/', {
        params: [{
          username: "jsmith",
          token: "token",
          method: "getProfile"
        }]
      })
      .respond({
        result: {
          address: "111 Main St."
          city: "Los Angeles",
          state: "CA"
        }
      });
      $httpBackend.flush();
      expect(ProfileDataService.profileData.address).toMatch("111 Main St.");
    }));
  });
});
```

The first test passes, but the second test states that profileData is undefined. They are identical tests. I am assuming that for each `it` that the ProfileDataService is being re-initialized, but that may not be the case. If that's not true, how do I create separate tests so that my service is destroyed and re-initialized for each test case?

The logic for the service is fairly straightforward:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('servicesModule')
  .service('ProfileDataService', ProfileDataService);

  ProfileDataService.$inject = ["$http", "$q", "LoginData", "CacheFactory"];

  function ProfileDataService($http, $q, LoginData, CacheFactory) {
    var ProfileDataService = this;
    (function() {
      init();
    })();

    function init() {
      getProfile().then(function(profileData) {
        ProileDataService.profileData = profileData;
      });
    }

    function getProfile() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var data = {
        params: [{
          username: LoginData.username,
          token: LoginData.token,
          method: "getProfile"
        }]
      };
      var profileDataCache = CacheFactory.get('profileDataCache');

      if (profileDataCache.get('profileData') && !invalidateCache) {
        deferred.resolve(profileDataCache.get('profileData'));
      }
      else {
        $http.post('http://mytestserver.com/api/', data)
        .success(function(data) {
          profileDataCache.put('profileData', response.result);
          deferred.resolve(data.result);
        });
      }
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
})();
```

I should also note that I've tried adding `rootScope.$digest()` in different places in the test, but that doesn't seem to make any difference. I thought manually triggering the digest cycle would ensure that the http post was caught and the response mocked.

Edit: I left out a huge detail... `angular-cache`. I forgot to mention that I was using a cacheing plugin. This was the reason for my problem. After creating a plunker and seeing that I was getting consistent results for identical tests, I knew there was something I was failing to realize. The second test was not making a POST request because of my cacheing logic.

Comment: How is the service defined?

Comment: `$httpBackend.flush()` triggers a digest, `$digest()` is redundant. Yes, for two identical specs the results should be identical. Tests are synchronous and don't contain anything that would leak the state between specs, so the cause of the problem is unknown. A plunk/fiddle that replicates the issue would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was failing to realize that my use of a cache was giving me different results for each test. Specifically, my service logic prevented a second POST to the api if a cache had already been persisted for that response.